# Remove v-on:click event programmatically from an element (VueJs)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, jsonresult

How do I remove the v-on:click event from a div?

```
<div v-on:click="RegistroT(1)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" 
         :disabled="HoraIngreso !== '00:00'">
     <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 
     <span id="TxtHoraIngreso" v-text="HoraIngreso"></span>
</div>
```

I tried this in a function called from the VueJS method **created** when the data is retrieved (from a JsonResult):

```
$('#TxtHoraIngreso').parent().addClass(this.HoraIngreso !== '00:00' ? 'disabled' : '');
```

But it does not work.

Basically, when a user registers his time of entry, the next time he enters the web the button must be deactivated.

Comment: `disabled` is not a property of `div`s so setting disabled will do nothing to help you.  Have you tried semantics e.g. using a `button`?

Comment: You have to create a method with setTimeOut function. like setTimeOut(()=> { this.isDisabled = true; }), 3000); And use a dynamic class binding https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html. e.g. :class="{ "className": isDisabled }". And 1 more adivce: Do not use jquery with vue/ang/react etc

Comment: I'll try using the `button`... i hope it works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I remove the v-on:click event from a div?

An easy way is to only call the event handler if the state is valid.

```
<button
  type="button"
  v-on:click="e => valid && onClickSubmit()"
>
  Sign Up
</button>
```

`onClickSubmit()` will only be executed if `valid = true`

Answer (score 2):

```
<template>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" :class="{'disabled': isDisabled}" @click="someMethodName"></button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default 
{
    data()
    {
        return {
            isDisabled: false
        }
    },
    methods:
    {
        someMethodName()
        {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.isDisabled = true;
            }, 3600);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But maybe I didn't understand your question ;>

Comment: Thanks, it works.
I use:  `this.HoraIngresoDisabled = this.HoraIngreso !== '00:00' ? true : false;` on .js.

Comment: And 
`<button v-on:click="RegistroT(1)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block " :class="{'disabled': HoraIngresoDisabled}" :disabled="HoraIngresoDisabled">
     <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 
     <span id="TxtHoraIngreso" v-text="HoraIngreso">--:--</span>
 </button>` 
on .cshtml

Comment: @RaulMiranda Great! Enjoy it! :)